# Re-install after Re-format

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2010

I have lost the Office Home and Student 2010 disk, but I have my product key.  How can I download the software and then apply my key?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft seems to have a solution here [Office 2010 Download](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/microsoft-office-2010-backup-FX101853122.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA101847520)  As noted on the link: "To download or order a backup DVD you will be required to provide a valid Office 2010 Product Key."

Answer (score 1):

Unless this has changed since the last time I tried, you should be able to download the trial version directly from Microsoft and then enter your existing key to activate it.